# ReadPendingException when using AsynchronousSocketChannel

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

I've been working with AsychronousSockets, but have run into the problem of receiving a ReadPendingException when running large loads.

**Some context:**
I want a client to asynchronously send a message to a server, and then listen for a response.

The response can be one of 3 types, and the read for an AsynchronousSocketChannel requires a predetermined sized ByteBuffer.

Thus, my solution for this was to have two reads: one to first receive the type of message (passed in as 4 bytes, an int) and then another read which will construct the appropriate sized byte buffer to handle the rest of the message.

I believe the main problem here comes with the fact that when the complete method of the CompletetionHandler is called, it does not necessarily mean that the read is complete for the ByteBuffer. To remedy this, I created a while loop that will read until the ByteBuffer is full.

This read in the while loop, however, seems to occasionally conflict with other reads, which is when I receive the ReadPendingException.

**Basic Skeleton Code:**

```
AsynchronousChannelGroup mThreadGroup= AsynchronousChannelGroup.withFixedThreadPool(100, Executors.defaultThreadFactory());
AsynchronousSocketChannel channel = AsynchronousSocketChannel.open(mThreadGroup);
InetSocketAddress hostAddress = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 12345);

// Connect to server
channel.connect(hostAddress, null, new CompletionHandler<Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    public void completed(Void result, Void attachment) {
        // Write some message to server
        ByteBuffer message = ...
        channel.write(message, null, new CompletionHandler<Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            public void completed(Void result, Void attachment) {
                // Now that we have sent the message, listen for a response type
                ByteBuffer responseType = ...
                channel.read(responseType, null, new CompletionHandler<Void, Void>() {

                    @Override
                    public void completed(Void result, Void attachment) {
                        // parse response type, do some other stuff...
                        // ...
                        // After other stuff, create new byte buffer for main message
                        ByteBuffer receiveMessage = ...
                        channel.read(receiveMessage, null, new CompletionHandler<Void, Void>() {

                            @Override
                            public void completed(Void result, Void attachment) {
                                // The read may not have been completed, so make sure that it is
                                while (receiveMessage.remaining() > 0) {
                                    channel.read(receiveMessage);
                                }

                                // Handle receiveMessage...
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void failed(Throwable exc, Void attachment) {}
                        });
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void failed(Throwable exc, Void attachment) {}
                });
            }

            public void failed(Throwable exc, Void attachment) {}
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void failed(Throwable exc, Void attachment) {}
});
```

So my question is thus two fold:

1. Is there a way of getting the code, as shown above, to work correctly (aka no longer receive the ReadPendingException)?
2. Is there a better way of setting up the same functionality?

Thank you guys in advance for any possible help.

Answer (score 1):

You should not loop inside the read completion method, especially without checking to see whether you have all the data first. You should *first* check to see whether you've received all the data you require, *then* if you *haven't*, issue *one more* read, using the same completion method. That process will recurse until it satisfies the first test.

Answer (score -1):

I think this exception is coming because another thread is trying invoke this completionHandler. Accesses will need to be synchronized on readCompletionHandler. Or, Try removing the while(remaining) loop in your ReadCompletionHandler. The completed callback function is invoked with bytesRead parameter. Use this value to create the buffer to read the message. For eg:

` class ClientReadCompletionHandler implements CompletionHandler {

```
private AsynchronousSocketChannel socket;
private ByteBuffer readBuffer;

public ClientReadCompletionHandler(AsynchronousSocketChannel socket, ByteBuffer readBuffer) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.readBuffer = readBuffer;
    System.out.println("readBuffer in constructor: " + readBuffer);
}

@Override
public void completed(Integer bytesRead, IOContext state) {
    if (bytesRead != null && bytesRead == -1) {
        try {
            socket.close();
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesRead];
    readBuffer.rewind();
    // Rewind the input buffer to read from the beginning

    readBuffer.get(buffer);

    if(readBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
        // process this readBuffer somehow to read all remaining data.
        // This will not be the place to call socket.read() again.

    }      
        readBuffer.clear();
        IOContext readState = new IOContext();  
   // Now read from socket again.
        socket.read(readBuffer, readState, this);
}
```

'

Comment: Another thread such as what?